# Unable to connect to slave in spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, ssh

I want to create a spark standalone cluster. I have 2 workstation and laptop. all have Ubuntu as their OS. Each of these systems have a different user-name. 
I followed this blog [Spark cluster](https://data-flair.training/blogs/install-apache-spark-multi-node-cluster/). I edited the hosts file

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts

10.8.9.13 master  
10.8.19.23 slave01  
10.8.5.158 slave02 

user-name of Master: lab   
user-name of Slave01: lab-zero   
user-name of  Slave02: computer
```

I have also generated the key value pairs `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and added it to the .ssh/authorized_keys file.
so when I ssh both machines I am able to log in without a password.
But when I run `./start-all.sh` it gives

```
lab@slave02's password: lab@slave01's password: localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/lab/Downloads/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-acs-lab-rg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-M1.out
```

It gets stuck here and both slaves are getting accessed using my default username `lab` instead of the username of the remote host (in this case the slave's username : `lab-zero` and `computer`)

And when I check the Spark Master UI, it gives me an error :

```
The requested URL could not be retrieved
```

Also when I type `./stop-slaves.sh` it returns

```
no org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop
```

This is my worker log :

```
17/11/30 01:53:40 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 16) 17/11/30 01:53:40 INFO Worker: Connecting to master
10.8.9.13:7077... 17/11/30 01:53:40 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master 10.8.9.13:7077 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult    
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)  
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)  
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)    
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)  
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)  
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)    
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)     
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)  
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)   
at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:218)  
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException    
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)  
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)    
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)    
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.readRpcAddress(NettyRpcEnv.scala:582)     
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:592)  
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:651)    
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:636)    
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:157)  
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105)     
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)    
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)   
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)   
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)   
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)   
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)    
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)     
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)     
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)  
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)  
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)    
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)     
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)     
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)     
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)    
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:189)   
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:120)    
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)   
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)   
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)   
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)   
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)   
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)    
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)     
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)     
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)     
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)  
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)  
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)    
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)     
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)     
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)     
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)    
    ... 1 more 17/11/30 01:54:43 ERROR Worker: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing all the system names to have the same name. Also created a `slaves` file in the master : ~/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/conf. The slaves file had the following content:

```
# A Spark Worker will be started on each of the machines listed below.
10.8.9.13   
10.8.19.23   
10.8.5.158
```

Also added the master IP address to the ~/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
/conf/spark-env.sh file

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.8.9.13
```

Answer (score 0):

- Run `./sbin/start-master.sh` on the master host, check
  availability in the ui, default port is `8080`.
- Run `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://10.8.9.13:7077` on each slave host.

  See [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) for more info.

Comment: When I run `./sbin/start-master.sh`  and check availability on the UI I get `Spark Master at spark://M1:7077/` after which I run the  `/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://10.8.9.13:7077` but the host does not show any worker to be alive. I also added
> 

    SPARK_MASTER_HOST=your_host_ip

    SPARK_LOCAL_IP=your_host_ip
 in my conf/spark-env.sh. but it does not seem to be working

Comment: @abhinavchoudhury have you try to run `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://M1:7077 ` instead of `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://10.8.9.13:7077 `?

Comment: yes, I did, still not showing anything on the master web UI. I also checked the logs in my slave machine. It is giving a Failed to connect to master M1:7077, error

Comment: Does the /etc/hosts file contains the master IP and the slave IP? Should, all the  slave hosts file also be the same as the master host file?
Also should the host-name of the system (M1) and master name be same? i.e. in my case the hostname is M1 and i have written 10.8.9.13 master in the host file.

Comment: try to run `netstat -nlp | grep 7077` on the master node and see if the master is listening on port 7077, if so, run `telnet M1 7077` from the slave node and see if port 7077 on the master is open

Comment: hosts file on the slave should have this record `10.8.9.13 M1` instead of `10.8.9.13 master`

Comment: ran netstat, gave the following output 
`10.8.9.13:7077 LISTEN`. Also ran `telnet M1 7077` go out put `connected to M1`

Comment: have you changed the hosts file in the slave?

Comment: changed host file on slave to `10.8.9.13 M1`. still giving `Failed to connect to master M1:7077 error `

Comment: try to disable your firewall, `sudo ufw disable` or `systemctl stop firewalld`